how to use `vi`/`vim` in cli mode like `sed`
i need to replace some strings and due to some reason, vi or vim is my only options.
but the problem is i need this to be done in a shell script, is it possible to use vi/vim in cli mode like sed?
e.g.
sed 's/hi/yo/g' la.txt

thanks

to edit "in-file", you should probably also have "ed" at your disposal ?

@OlivierDulac A system without sed probably does not have ed installed. For whatever reason, some Linux systems don't come with ed preinstalled. Both sed and ed are easily installed via packages though, or usable via Docker containers.

@Kusalananda: indeed, I didn't think about minimalist setups (such as some containers).

Regarding "vi or vim is my only options" - why? sed, for example, is a mandatory POSIX tool that should be present on all Unix-like systems so is the issue that sed isn't available on your box or that this is a homework problem about learning vim or something else?
